# make an input invisible but clickable through CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way of making an **input radio invisible** via CSS only?

I've got the following layout: http://jsfiddle.net/t87k5k8u/2/

```
<label class="main">
    <input name="rad-1" type="radio" checked=""/>
    <div></div>
</label>
<label class="main">
    <input name="rad-1" type="radio" />
    <div></div>
</label>
<label class="main">
    <input name="rad-1" type="radio" />
    <div></div>
</label>
```

As you see in the example, the radio is appearing on top. How can I make appear on the back and be clickable or even hide it while letting it be clickable?

Comment: invisible but clickable? you mean you are going to trigger click of one element which is invisible with some other element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `opacity: 0` to the `input` might be a start. Not sure about browser support, but it seems to work on the newest versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

```css
.main {
    position: relative
}
.main > div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f00;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
input:checked + div {
    background: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also hide the input and only show a label. I modified a couple of things from the fiddle to give you an example:

HTML:

```
<label class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div></div>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    position: relative
    display: block;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I have only copied the modified CSS blocks, the rest remain unchanged.

Comment: Won't work because events are not fired on `visibility:hidden` elements. See this non-working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t87k5k8u/14/

Comment: Yes but! If you click on the label, the event is fired. Therefore, by changing your "<div class='main'>" into a "<label class='main'>", it works.

Comment: Opps, yeah you're right. My Bad. Sorry. I'd remove my down-vote but the system wont let me unless you make an edit. (maybe you can make a tiny format change or something?)

Answer (score 3):

Sure.
You can make the input go invisible.

Set

```
opacity:0;
```

Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t87k5k8u/10/).

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS Opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity). Make sure its too faint to be seen but not actually fully transparent so that the browser still renders it (for maximum x-browser compatibility):

```
opacity:0.02; /* not FULLY transparent */
filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE8 and lower */
zoom: 1; /* Triggers "hasLayout" in IE 7 and lower */
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t87k5k8u/13/

```css
.main {
    position: relative
}
.main > div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f00;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity:0.02; /* not FULLY transparent */
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* IE8 and lower */
    zoom: 1; /* Triggers "hasLayout" in IE 7 and lower */
}
input:checked + div {
    background: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my proposal:

**Example fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/u0xLkz05/2/

---

For this task I would use the `for` attribute in the `label` elements and, since you're placing a `div` inside an inline element, I would slightly change and simplify the markup like so

```
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="your-id1" name="..." />
        <label for="your-id1">Your label 1</label> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="your-id2" name="..." />
        <label for="your-id2">Your label 2</label> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="your-id3" name="..." />
        <label for="your-id3">Your label 3</label> 
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and the CSS would be

```
fieldset div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font: 0/0 a;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input + label { background: red; }
input:checked + label { background: black; }
```

---

Each radio element becomes not visible due to the label element which is positioned in `absolute`. Instead of a div you could change the background colour of the label.

As a side note with this approach you don't need to use an extra empty element, the semantic is improved and the use of label elements increases the accessibility of your form (without CSS enabled you would see all the checkboxes with theirs associated label aside)